# Mass Assignment confusion in rails association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, mass-assignment

Having some trouble with something I'm sure is basic, but also having trouble finding a good answer here on SO.

I have a Users table and an Authorization table, here are my models:

```
##Authorization.rb
class Authorization < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :provider, :uid, :user_id
  belongs_to :user
  validates :provider, :uid, :presence => true


  def self.find(auth_hash)
    find_by_provider_and_uid(auth_hash["provider"],
                             auth_hash["uid"])
  end

  def self.create_with_hash(auth_hash)
    #if they've already registered, then just return that authorization

    unless auth = find_by_provider_and_uid(auth_hash["provider"],
                                           auth_hash["uid"])
      user = User.create(name: auth_hash["info"]["name"],
                         email: auth_hash["info"]["email"],
                         nickname: nil,
                         firstname: auth_hash["info"]["first_name"],
                         location: auth_hash["user_location"]
                         )

      auth = create(user: user,
                    provider: auth_hash["provider"],
                    uid: auth_hash["uid"])
    end

    auth
  end

end
```

And my User model:

```
##User.rb
require 'bcrypt'

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include BCrypt

  #accessible and settable properties
  attr_accessible  :name, :email, :nickname, :firstname, :location

  #relations
  has_many :authorizations, dependent: :destroy

  #validations
  validates :name, :email, :firstname,  :presence => true
  validates :email, :uniqueness => true
  validates :nickname, :uniqueness => true

  #always make sure their email and nickname are lowercased
  def before_validation(user)
    user.email.downcase!
    user.email = Password.create(email)
    user.nickname.downcase!
  end

  def after_save(user)
    user.email = Password.new(user.email)
  end

  def is_nickname_available?(nickname)
    Users.find_by_nickname(nickname.downcase).blank?
  end

  def add_nickname(user_id, nickname)
    #todo: error handling
    user = Users.find(user_id).update_attribute(nickname: nickname)
  end

  def add_provider(auth_hash)
    #Check if the provider already exists, so we don't add it twice
    unless
      authorizations.find_by_provider_and_uid(auth_hash["provider"],
                                              auth_hash["uid"])
      Authorization.create    user_id:self.id,
        provider: auth_hash["provider"],
        uid: auth_hash["uid"]
    end
  end

end
```

In a controller, if I try to do: `Authorization.create_with_hash(auth_hash)`, I get the error:

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: user
```

On the line `auth = create(user: user,
                    provider: auth_hash["provider"],
                    uid: auth_hash["uid"])` in my Authorization.rb model.

So, I'm very new to this, but am not clear on why this doesn't work. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks
Mustafa

Answer (score 0):

Use `attr_accessible :provider, :uid, :user` should work. Or change

```
auth = create(user: user,
              provider: auth_hash["provider"],
              uid: auth_hash["uid"])
```

to

```
auth = create(user_id: user.id,
              provider: auth_hash["provider"],
              uid: auth_hash["uid"])
```